# Format labels in an ExtJS 6 bar-chart

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs6

In [extjs4](/questions/tagged/extjs4) I used the `renderer` property of a label (assigned to an axis in a bar chart) to format the value. ***e.g.*** with something like:

```js
axes = [{
    type: 'numeric',
    position: 'left',
    label: {
        renderer: function(v) {
            return String(v) + 'KB';
        }
    }
    ...
```

According to the [`Ext.chart.label.Label` manual](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.chart.label.Label) this config property has been removed in newer versions.  How can I achieve this in ExtJS Version 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-modern/#!/api/Ext.chart.axis.Numeric-cfg-renderer) it's on the axis not the label itself so your config should probably look something like:

```js
var axes = [
    {
        type: 'numeric',
        position: 'left',
        renderer: function(axis, data){
            return data.label + 'KB';
        },
        label: {
            // optional label style config.
        }
    }
    // ...
];
```

Comment: In ExtsJs 6.2.0 the rendered function synopsis is either : `function(axis, labelText, layoutContext, lastLabelText)`